# Android: Issues with my asking for permissions. Code inside

Tags: java, android

I am trying to give the user an option to grant permission in my code as per Google best practices. The code below is what I have tried. The first time I ran it on the emulator it asked for a permission. Nothing else was done. No toast showed up, no green "Granted" text, etc. Logcat is silent on the issue. Does anyone see what have I missed? (Note: This code is inside a fragment).

```
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button getPermissions = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.get_permissions);
        TextView permissionsText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.permissions_text);

        getPermissions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(checkPermission()){
                    permissionsText.setText("Granted");
                    permissionsText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });
}

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                {
                        ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                        CALL_PHONE,
                        INTERNET,
                        READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        VIBRATE,
                        USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT
                }, RequestPermissionCode);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean fineLocPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean coarseLocPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean backgroundLocPermission = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean phonePermission = grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean internetPermission = grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean readExternalStoragePermission = grantResults[5] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean vibratePermission = grantResults[6] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean fullScreenIntentPermission = grantResults[7] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (fineLocPermission && coarseLocPermission && backgroundLocPermission && phonePermission && internetPermission && readExternalStoragePermission && vibratePermission && fullScreenIntentPermission)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {

        int FirstPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int SecondPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        int ThirdPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
        int FourthPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), CALL_PHONE);
        int FifthPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), INTERNET);
        int SixthPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int SeventhPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), VIBRATE);
        int EigthPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT);

        return FirstPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                SecondPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ThirdPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                FourthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                FifthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                SixthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                SeventhPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                EigthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Fragment use `requestPermissions(arrayOfPermissions, REQ_CODE)` instead of `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`:

A Fragment has a method named `requestPermissions()` and I **don't** mean the method you named it in your code.

`onRequestPermissionsResult` is then invoked correctly in the Fragment.

Sample Code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, REQ_CODE_PERMISSION);
}
```